# Adobe Flex unable to load images from Amazon S3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, amazon-s3, flex3, crossdomain.xml

I have a flex 3 app that is attempting to load images from Amazon S3. The images fail to load, so I fired up debug mode. In debug mode, the images load, but I also get the following output in the debugger:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://something.s3.amazonaws.com/logos/mylogo.png' tried to access incompatible context 'http://localhost/myapp/bin-debug/index.html?debug=true'
```

I have added a crossdomain.xml file into the root of my bucket as follows, but this does not seem to help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only" />
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: How are the images being loaded? Is it just a simple Loader.load(URLRequest) call?

Comment: Nope, just logo_image.source = 'http://something.s3.amazonaws.com/logos/mylogo.png';

Answer (score 2):

Maybe problem in site authorization. When I visited your [url](http://something.s3.amazonaws.com/logos/mylogo.png) I got "Access Denied". It works for one env but not for other.

Your don't need crossdomain.xml for just displaying images in your way with *image.source*, so problem not in Flash Player security.

You trace says that image is loaded but it can't access parent sandbox. It doesn't help to debug problem. Try to use [ServiceCapture](http://kevinlangdon.com/serviceCapture/) or Firebug or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to define of what actually being loaded to Flash Player.